# Hello, Can anybody give suggestion on following?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<nav id="mainnav-container">
<div id="mainnav">
<!--Menu-->
<!--================================-->
<div id="mainnav-menu-wrap">
<div class="nano has-scrollbar">
<div class="nano-content" tabindex="0" style="right: -17px;">
<ul id="mainnav-menu" class="list-group">
<li class="first" icon="fa fa-gbp" icon2="arrow" title="budget">
<li icon="fa fa-pie-chart" icon2="arrow">
<li icon="fa fa-tasks" icon2="arrow" title="deliver">
<li icon="fa fa-users" icon2="arrow" title="contacts">
<li class="last" icon="fa fa-file-text" icon2="arrow" title="reports">
<a href="/report">
<ul class="menu-title menu_level_1 collapse" aria-expanded="false">
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="nano-pane" style="display: none;">
```

Above is my HTML code and i am trying to click on Title reports and I have tried following:

1) driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mainnav-menu-wrap']/div/div[1]/ul/li[5]/a"));

2) driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mainnav-menu-wrap']/div/div[1]/ul/li[5] li[contains(@title, 'reports')]"));

But doesn't seems to be working.. Can anybody please help ?

Answer (score 1):

> I would try, By.xpath("//div[@class="nano-content"]//li[@title="reports"])

On a side note, if you are using firfox, try installing "firebug" which is a cool addon for locating unique element in page. If you are using chrome, try "xpath checker"

Comment: I tried using firbug and firepath, but the Xpath that gave me is not unique, so i had to use this one, I am pretty sure the Xpath I have written is correct as when i put this in the Firpath, it matches the value Report value which i wanted to click

Comment: Hi, when i tried your work and tried t click it didn't work, but when i tried to print this with getText(); it did print exactly :) not sure why this is happening.. what i tried is:                                                                String Report= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='nano-content']//li[@title='reports']")).getText();                                                    and then I Print Reports, then it is printing it perfectly and then when again i tried ".click"  it doesnt work

Comment: Check if the element is clickable. Install firepath plugin in firefox and inspect the element in the firepath checker. You will be able to figure out if the element is clickable or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try any of these below mentioned `xpath`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@title='reports']/a")).click();
```

**Explanation of xpath:** Use `title` attribute of `<li>` tag and move ahead to `<a>` tag.

> OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@title='reports'][@class='last']/a")).click();
```

**Explanation of xpath:** Use `title` and `class` attribute of `<li>` tag and move ahead to `<a>` tag.

> OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='mainnav-menu']/li[@title='reports']/a")).click();
```

> OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='nano-content']/ul[@id='mainnav-menu']/li[@title='reports']/a")).click();
```

> OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='nano-content']//following::li[@title='reports']/a")).click();
```

> OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='nano-content']/..//li[@title='reports']/a")).click();
```

**Note:-** Instead of using `absolute xpath`, use `relative xpath`.

Comment: Hi, I have tried all the above Xpath- i cannot use class "last" as its value changes run-time.. also the "last" class is not unique in my code, has been used for other element.

Comment: Then you should use `title` attribute of `<li>` tag.  `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@title='reports']/a")).click();` or `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@title='reports'][@class='last']/a")).click();`

Comment: Have you tried my updated answer? Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, apology for late repl.. I did work.. Many Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

According to: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

This is the correct syntax:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='mainnav-menu-wrap']/div/div[1]/ul/li[5]/a"));
```

No `.*`

Comment: Sorry, I have tried without .* it still gives me exception:Your exception is====org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException

Comment: Thank you so very much, for all the time and responses..I tried with thread.sleep.. Looks like page wasn't loading properly and it was tryig to click.. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='mainnav-menu-wrap']/div/div[1]/ul/li[@class='last']"));`

or

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[*id='mainnav-menu-wrap']/div/div[1]/ul/li[@class='last']"));`

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I tried with this as well, but the class last is dynamic

Comment: Thank you so very much, for all the time and responses..I tried with thread.sleep.. Looks like page wasn't loading properly and it was trying to click.. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you're using such a long xpath? Looking at it you should just be able to use `//li[@title='reports']/a`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, actually No element is unique in the html, i dont understand how will  //li[@title='reports']/a will work ? sorry i am new to this so trying to understand,

Comment: No need to apologise, this is what the sites here for :) The xpath I've put will look for an li tag which has the title reports, looking at the code you've put there's only 1 which matches that. When you say no element is unique, do you mean there are other list items not pasted above which have the same title?

Comment: Thanks for your replay. No i think i put it wrongly, ur interpretation is correct there is only one li with title report .. Can you please refer my above comment?                                                                                             I tried this :   String Report= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='nano-content']//l‌​i[@title='reports']"‌​)).getText();         and then I Print Reports,               and it is printing it perfectly and then when again i tried ".click" it doesnt work again :( i wonder why this is happening.

Comment: The above code gave me this in console: I have clicked========= Reports                                                                                                          
Budget Overview
Budget Update
Published Budget Report
Budget Tracker
Media Type
Workflow RAG Report
Customer Project Overview
Macro Plan Report
Micro Plan Report
WSI Report    (These are all the reports name which are beneath that report link)

Comment: Thank you so very much, for all the time and responses..I tried with thread.sleep.. Looks like page wasn't loading properly and it was tryig to click.. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you are able to get data by using below code it should work for click as well.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='nano-content']//l‌​i[@title='reports']"‌​)).getText();
```

By any chance did you miss to add a href tag on xpath before performing click on it.Please try with below one.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='nano-content']/l‌​i[@title='reports']/a"‌​)).click();
```

Comment: I am sorry for being pain, but I seriously dont understand whats the issue: when i added "driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='nano-content']/li[@title='reports']/a")).click();"     It says --> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:

Comment: I tried List<WebElement> ReportList =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='nano-content']/li[@title='reports']"));                                                              System.out.println("My LI List is===========" + ReportList);                           But even the Report list is Empty

Comment: Is Page loading completed before you perform click? Try by adding some hard wait like Thread.sleep(5000) before perform click. 

And the best approach is before clicking on any element we should check whether element is displayed and enabled?

Comment: Thank you! let me try with your suggestion! ill keep you updated! Many Thanks!

Comment: Thread.sleep worked... yay.. Cant thank you enough for your suggestion, really made my day.. Thank you so very much!